# How to insert an object into SQL using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to insert some string variables into a DB with nodeJS following parsing the text from the DOM.

I'm using cheerio for that , here's an example that I'm trying to write to my db, it type tests as a string and outputs a score out of 10 e.g 3.5 out of 10.
    var kf = $('span.glyphicons.glyphicons-star').attr('title')

My code for the sql is as follows, I can't seem  to find anywhere how to define the variable in the sql query line:

```
con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");
var sql = "INSERT INTO juice (ratescore) VALUES ('" + con.escape(kf) + "')";
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("1 record inserted");
});
});
```

Comment: Add the values for "kf", print the string variable "sql" what it says.

Comment: there is no need to define variable in query line instead define before query and then add into string. also you can use backticks for making query string 
``INSERT INTO juice (ratescore) VALUES ('${con.escape(kf)}')``

Comment: In the end wrote my variables into an array and encased it in [] in the query, Thanks!